# What location (in windows) git files will be stored by default?

Tags: spring, github, gradle

I have downloaded Spring Source from github as below
git clone git://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework.git

The console message as below:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework.git
Cloning into 'spring-framework'...
remote: Counting objects: 115615, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (36847/36847), done.
remote: Total 115615 (delta 62280), reused 114048 (delta 61512)
Receiving objects: 100% (115615/115615), 25.73 MiB | 254 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (62280/62280), done.
Checking out files: 100% (6191/6191), done.
```

Now which location these files will be stored? (I am using Windows Vista)
Also I need to run gradle build and gradle install (as per https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework#building-from-source).t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git clone` takes two arguments, a repo and a path to clone to.  If no path is specified, it creates a directory in the current directory with the same name as the repo.  So in your case, the files will be located in a folder called **spring-framework** in the directory you ran the command from.

Comment: Actually I am using Git Bash, so I don't know which path I am into.

Comment: type `pwd` in git bash to see your current path.